# How to create custom search result source + display template

Tags: search-results, display-template, result-source

This is the desired scenario:

User searches for something and if that something comes from a particular list, swap out the Search Result title(link), with the list item's `Url` field.

If the search finds results from any other list, remove it from the results.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to show results only from one list?

Comment: No, I mean I want to show everything that is NOT a list item (documents, etc), but if it comes from a particular list then add the results together with everything else and modify the main link in the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following query to get the result

```
path:"https://siteurl"  (ListID:{CC6FB9E2-92CE-444E-85C7-2E126DFF9ED0} OR contentclass<>SPListItem OR)
```

The above query will give you all results which are not of type `SPListItem`. If you observe there is an `OR` condition where we are including search results from a single list. So in your case you should change the `GUID` to the guid of your list.

Before you modify DisplayTemplate, you should include the Managed Property for `Url` using `mso:ManagedPropertyMapping`

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1.aspx